# background image on link hover using css/html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to get an image to show up behind a link when I hover over the link in my navigation. This is for a school assignment where I can only use css, html, and a bootstrap template. 
Here is my html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
      <div class="container">
       <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="about.html"> Home </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownPortfolio" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> SHOP </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPortfolio">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-1-col.html"> BASICS </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="portfolio-2-col.html"> TOURIST </a>
               </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct css but I tried both and neither show the image I want when I hover.

```
 li:hover {
    background-image: url(images/scribble.png);}
a:hover {
    color: silver;
    background-image: url(images/scribble.png);}
```

The a:hover definitely changes the color of my font. [This](https://tsuki-co-uk.myshopify.com/) is the site I'm replicating for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your assignment, I will give you some hints:

- Treat the image as a content of a **pseudo element** in css.
- Use `z-index` to bring an element on top of another one.
- Look for solutions to put a div in front (on top) of another div using `position`

Comment: my professor is allowing us to ask for help on stackoverflow to get answers and thank you for your hints but this doesn't really help me since I haven't learned these concepts yet.